# Get the list of all environment names of Elastic beanstalk using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using below python code to get the ApplicationName and EnvironmentName of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Can anyone please let me know how to print/get all the environment names by using for loop or some other way. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
import json

def get_info():
    try:
        eb = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk',"us-east-1")
        response = eb.describe_environments()
        app_name=(response['Environments'][0]['ApplicationName'])
        env_name=(response['Environments'][0]['EnvironmentName'])
        print app_name
        print env_name
    except:
        raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_info()
```

Comment: `response['Environments']` seems to be a list. Why not looping over it and get all the ApplicationName and EnvironmentName

Comment: @SRC please let me know an example syntax on how to do the loop

Comment: You just need a for loop. https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop You really shouldn't need an example provided for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the code, as I have no way to test it presently, however, assuming that `response['Environments']` is a list, the following should work. Please note that, if it is not a list then it will not work or you may have to change the code a bit to get the right result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
import json

def get_info():
    try:
        eb = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk',"us-east-1")
        response = eb.describe_environments()
        for item in response['Environments']:
            app_name = response['Environments'][item]['ApplicationName']
            env_name = response['Environments'][item]['EnvironmentName']
            print app_name
            print env_name
    except:
        raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_info()
```

Also, given the fact that you are using a try-except block, I will say that it is always wiser to catch the particular exception you want to catch. I am not sure which that will be, but a `all-catch` except is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@SRC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587118/src); I made below changes to your script to get it working for me.

```
 app_name = item['ApplicationName']
 env_name = item['EnvironmentName']
```